# HTMX - Transition on target element

Tags: css, htmx

I've been experimenting with HTMX recently and I cant seem to find a way to apply a transition to a target element. I have a form that submits a GET request and returns a table.

```
<form class="mt-3" hx-get="/data/statement/AJAX" hx-target="#statementAJAX" >
```

It basically returns a div containing the table like this:

```
<div id="statementAJAX" class="fade-in">

</div>
```

the CSS for the div is the following:

```
.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}


@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Now the css transition works when i first load the page but when I execute the AJAX request nothing happens.

I tried apllying style="opacity:0" to the form but obviously it applies only to the form and not the target...

Any idea how to apply the transition to the target element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there works for me. Are you trying to replace the entire table or add to the table?

This works for me using your CSS and `hx-swap="outerHTML"` to replace the table.

```
<a href="#" id="test" hx-get="/load.html" hx-target="#table" hx-trigger="click" hx-swap="outerHTML">
      Submit
</a>

<div id="table" class="fade-in"></div>
```

`load.html`

```
<div id="table" class="fade-in">
    table content
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried adding hx-swap="outterHTML" but it didin't work for me. My form wouldn't work after I submitted the first request and the transition didn't work. Also to answer your question (which I should have stated) I"m trying to replace the entire table

Comment: Make sure you are using `outerHTML` with one "t".  That would ensure the entire table is replaced if your response includes the entire table like `load.thtml` in my example.

Comment: You can see it live here https://codepen.io/jreviews/project/editor/XkMqEx

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me. Your codepen helped me understand that outerHTML changed the entire div, not just the content inside. In my previous version, I didn't use the outer swap so the AJAX call would return the table but without the div. I was keeping the original div this entire time, I guess that's what was keeping me from applying the transition. Thanks again!